# Loading SAS code from text file inside a data step

Tags: sas

Assume that I have a SAS data step, where I subtract every observation (say, I only have variable `X`) from its mean:

```
data tmp;
  set tmp;
  x = x-2;
run;
```

Let's say mean is not always `2` and I have another script that creates a text file with one line, which contains:

```
x = x-2;
```

Now, the question is, is there any way I can have something like:

```
data tmp;
  set tmp;
  load text_file;
run;
```

To do the same thing as the first data step? In other words, I want a solution that relies on using the content of the file (either as I showed in the data step or within a macro).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

%INCLUDE will do what you want.  Assuming your text file "c:\mycode.sas" has the line

```
x=x-2;
```

then you can do this:

```
data tmp;
set tmp;
%include "c:\mycode.sas";
run;
```

I'd note that this is a really, really bad way to do this, but it's what you asked for.

If I wanted to subtract the mean of x from x (standardizing the data), I'd either use PROC STDIZE, or do this:

```
proc means data=tmp;
var x;
output out=x_mean mean=x_bar;
run;

data want;
set tmp;
if _n_ = 1 then set x_mean;
x=x-x_bar;
run;
```

Or, PROC STDIZE (included in SAS/STAT):

```
proc stdize data=tmp out=want_std method=mean;
var x;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks Joe! Great answer; exactly what I was looking for. Basically, the text file is not as simple as "x=x-2" and is a dynamically-generated SAS code and hence those procs might not work for me in this case, however, for std, I quite like your solution and will surely use it.